# suppress stream_socket_client warnings

Tags: php, error-handling

I have a line of code

```
$result = stream_socket_client($target, $errno, $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT);
```

That throws a warning if the connection was not successful

```
WARNING: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
```

I need to suppress the warning. Adding @ so that the lines looks

```
$result = @stream_socket_client($target, $errno, $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT);
```

does not help. PHP just seems to ignore the @

What am I missing here?

Comment: Not sure, why @ didn't work for you. It might be a php version problem. I just tried @ after reading your question and it worked. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not nice solution, but you can disable warning messages for a while:

```
$oldErrorReporting = error_reporting(); // save error reporting level
error_reporting($oldErrorReporting ^ E_WARNING); // disable warnings
$result = stream_socket_client($target, $errno, $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT);
error_reporting($oldErrorReporting); // restore error reporting level
```

Comment: works fine, although I figured out a more clear option. I added a new answer

Comment: If warning level is already disabled, ^E_WARNING will enable it. Recommended to change it to ($oldErrorReporting & ~E_WARNING)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution using custom error handlers

```
set_error_handler(function(){return true;});
stream_socket_client($target, $errno, $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT);
restore_error_handler();
```

Comment: Also nice solution, but remember, that setting internal configuration value is significantly faster than changing script-wide error handler to a new anonymous callback :)